# XSLT - add image to a file

Tags: c#, html, xslt

I have a `XSLT` file in Visual Studio where I need to add some pictures. Whenever I use a relative path does not work, only with the absolute path.

My code looks like:

```
<xsl:if test="ranting=5.0">
<img src="..\..\img\fiveStars.jpg" width="150" height="50" />     
</xsl:if>
```

But it does not work. I have a folder where I have the `XSLT` file and the `img` folder with the images inside.

Comment: `../` is one directory above, `../../` is two directories above, and so on, so you have to show us your folder structure. And here may be you need like this: `<img src="../img/fiveStars.jpg" width="150" height="50" />`

Comment: It does not work either

Comment: *So, you should show us your folder structure*

Comment: img folder: C:\Users\MaríaAdelaida\Desktop\aida puta\Hotel Reservations -current                                                                                                       xslt file: C:\Users\MaríaAdelaida\Desktop\aida puta\Hotel Reservations -current\Hotel

Comment: using  `<xsl:variable name="myVar" as="xs:boolean" select="true()"/>` and then using   `<xsl:when test="$myVar">`, does it show the image?

Comment: Your test is for `ranting`=5, just a guess but perhaps that is meant to be `rating`?

Comment: The XSLT is creating some HTML. How is this HTML actually being displayed in your application?